# "¿Puede escindirse el castellano en el futuro?" on hold?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, preguntas-cerradas

Veo que mi pregunta [¿Puede escindirse el castellano en el futuro?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13376/puede-escindirse-el-castellano-en-el-futuro) se ha cerrado con el siguiente motivo:

> put on hold as primarily opinion-based by AlexBcn, Gorpik, Joze♦ 2
>   hours ago
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the
>   help center, please edit your question.

No estoy de acuerdo con tal acción. Revisando cómo se ha respondido, se observa cómo el tema puede enfocarse de una forma bastante objetiva, estableciendo qué elementos pueden influir en tal situación.

[Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego) lo explica de una forma muy concisa:

> No entiendo por qué esta pregunta está "on hold". Quizá necesite una
>   discusión en la sección meta, pero no creo que esta pregunta sea
>   simplemente "opinion based". A pesar de que es imposible predecir el
>   futuro, todas las respuestas aportan datos más o menos objetivos. La
>   pregunta es "Puede escindirse ..." y no "Se escindirá ...", que creo
>   que es variante suficiente como para poder ser respondida con los
>   datos "a mano" y conocimiento suficiente sin que sea simplemente
>   opinión de cada uno.. –  Diego 18 mins ago

Podría darse el caso que la pregunta recibiera respuestas del tipo comentario personal, pero eso puede ocurrir en cualquier pregunta (de hecho, ocurre bastante), pero considero que esta pregunta puede resultar una pieza académica la mar de interesante y, por ello, insisto en que estaría bien que fuera reabierta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que es una buena pregunta.

De hecho, preguntas de este tipo son bastante comunes en SE Linguistics, y las respuestas enfocan en el cómo, basándose en los procesos lingüísticos, culturales, históricos, etc.

Si fuese algo como «¿Puede que el castellano sea el idioma principal de EEUU en el futuro?», también la marcaría como demasiado sujetiva.

Pero era más bien, «¿Puede que algún proceso lingüístico —uno que acaece con frecuencia con las lenguas— pase al castellano en el futuro relativemente previsible?  Y, en su caso, ¿cuáles son las circunstancias que lo favorecerían o lo desfacorecerían?»

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que la puse en "on hold" porque pide razones específicas por las cuales el español *podría* escindirse. Las respuestas no pueden ser objetivas, todas las respuestas van a ser producto de especulación o hipótesis que no son válidas (no se pueden comprobar).

Lo único que se podría hacer sería un análisis de comparación con lenguas que sí se dividieron, mirar cuales son las similitudes entre dichas lenguas y el español e intentar sacar una conclusión. Una conclusión que en todo caso no sería la última palabra dado que el tema es tan incierto.

No estoy de acuerdo con Diego ni con guifa. Una respuesta que sería correcta sería:

> **Sí.** El español se puede escindir en el futuro como **cualquier otra lengua**. Factores que favorecerían tal escisión sería la divergencia de culturas, o la dislocación geográfica de las poblaciones. **Lo cual aplica a todas las lenguas.**

Como también:

> **No.** El español no se puede escindir dado que vivimos en un mundo globalizado y las poblaciones que lo hablan están en constante intercambio. Por ello el aislamiento de las poblaciones, cultural o geográfico es de gran improbabilidad, tomando en cuenta que las culturas latinas y la iberoamericana tienen más similitudes que diferencias. **Lo cual se aplica a gran parte de las grandes lenguas (francés, inglés, alemán, japonés, chino, hindi...)**

Estoy de acuerdo que la pregunta resulta en un **debate** interesante y es precisamente por esa razón que está en on hold. No hay una o dos respuestas definitivas sino potencialmente decenas. Y aún más importante, tales respuestas se contradicen y me sorprendería que no se pudiesen aplicar a otras lenguas.

Dado que estamos en la página de **Spanish language & Usage** esa pregunta no se adapta a los temas que son aceptados. Un lugar donde esta pregunta sería mucho más apropiada sería en **Linguistics Stack Exchange**.

---

Pero bueno estoy de acuerdo que la pregunta entra más bien en una zona gris de lo que es aceptable o no. Yo veo el vaso más medio vacío por eso voté por cerrarla. A fin de cuentas la comunidad tiene la última palabra de abrirla o no. Para eso tenemos esta discusión.

Comment: Yo también la vote por la misma razón. No puede marcarse como correcta una respuesta que generaría varias páginas de debate en un foro, en este caso, que pregunta sería marcada como aceptable? Aquella que se aproxime más a la opinión del OP o la que obtenga más puntos? El que quiere aprender castellano busca respuesta a sus dudas, no un debate, sería mas apropiado en el portal Linguistics. Aunque bien es cierto que se agradece la pregunta de fedorqui tanto en el Spanish como en el Meta y la lectura de sus respuestas.

Comment: @AlexBcn y Joze, gracias por vuestras aportaciones. Creo que el conjunto de motivos que pueden llevar a un idioma a escindirse es bastante objetivable y eso es lo que preguntaba yo. La respuesta de guifa demuestra que puede ser respondible sin caer en la metafísica, de ahí que siga pensando que no es "opinion based" sino "facts based". Sí veo que el tipo de pregunta no está incluido en [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pero no vería mal una extensión de temas para hacer el sitio más interesante.

Comment: Puesto que solo falto yo de quienes votaron por cerrar la pregunta, diré que estoy de acuerdo con los motivos que expresan Joze y @AlexBcn, más lo que apunta el propio fedorqui (no es el tipo de preguntas para ese foro). Esto no significa que no pueda ser una discusión interesante; solo que no es el formato de Spanish Language.